# Add and drag new item by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want create an effect "taking stone from bowl". New div element ".stone" should creating under mouse cursor by clicking on specified div ".bowl". The stone should be straight draggable while the user click and press the mouse.

All I could write is adding new element that user can move by second click, but not by first:

```
$(".bowl").on('mousedown', function ( event ) {
        var $stone = $('<div class="stone"></div>').css({
            left: event.pageX - 25,
            top: event.pageY - 25,
            position: "absolute"
        });
        $(this).parent().append($stone);
        $stone.draggable();
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rzab2h5u/

How I can do it right way?

Comment: `click` only fires when you release the button, give a try with `mousedown`

Comment: @Kaddath I can add `mousedown` to the `.bowl` but how I can catch this event in a `.stone` and drag it?

Comment: I make something like https://jsfiddle.net/50rLotng/ Probably, this is the only way to do that.

Comment: i don't have time to write a proper solution and test it, but the way i would do this is to create the draggable stone with a `hidden` class, and instead of adding it in the event, just make it visible with another class or removing `hidden`. Similar to your new fiddle, but without adding/removing from DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by basically passing the event to the draggable after it's been created. Reference: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/trigger-draggable-on-mousedown

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/s3tfa3dr/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var bowl = $(".bowl");

  bowl.droppable({
    accept: ".stone",
    greedy: true,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.detach();
    }
  });

  bowl.on('mousedown', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $stone = $('<div>', {
      class: "stone",
      id: "stone-" + ($(".stone").length + 1)
    }).css({
      left: event.pageX - 25,
      top: event.pageY - 25,
      position: "absolute"
    }).appendTo($this.parent()).draggable({
      start: function(ui, event) {
        console.log("Drag Started");
      }
    });
    $stone.trigger(event);
  });
});
```

We basically re-trigger the same event on the new object.